# Ajax not working after deploying to Azure

Tags: ajax, azure, asp.net-core-2.0

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC Core. Everything works perfect on my local machine but whenever I deploy to Azure the Ajax calls always get a `404 Not Found`.

Here's a snippet of one controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetPublicHolidays()
{
    var events = adminService.GetPublicHolidays();
    return new JsonResult(events);
}
```

And here's the Ajax call:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetPublicHolidays","Admin")',
```

Comment: To determine where the actual problem is: 1. Please call the API directly, for example by using Postman. What is the result? 2. Open up developer tools in your browser and see what URL the Ajax call is pointing to (press F12 and have a look at the Network tab). Is it correct?

Comment: 1.Returns 404 not found error too
2. The Ajax call points to GetPublicHolidays in network tab
@rickvdbosch

Comment: @rickvdbosch
How can I fix that please as it's my first time deploying a webApp and I am kinda lost
And how also is the API not there though other functions in the same controller file are working but not with ajax calls ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the URL to an action in an ASP.NET Controller is **not the name of the method**. There's a lot going on [by convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in ASP.NET.

As an example, this is a default ASP.NET Core API controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

As you can see in the comment, the route is `<baseUrl>/api/values`. This route is comprised of the base URL, the `api` prefix and the **name of the controller**. Because you add a `HttpGetAttribute`, ASP.NET knows that is the Get method.

So, considering this controller:

```
public class RandomController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> WhateverWeirdMethodName()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

The URL for the `GET` request would be `<baseUrl>/api/random`